# Add missing data using ffill on Pandas DataFrame with duplicate DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV input file that looks something like this

```
date,server_cluster,server,cpu,watt
2023-03-29 12:00:00,cluster1,server1,cpu1,104
2023-03-29 12:00:00,cluster1,server1,cpu2,105
2023-03-29 12:00:00,cluster1,server2,cpu1,122
2023-03-29 12:00:00,cluster1,server2,cpu2,103
2023-03-29 12:00:00,cluster2,server1,cpu1,105
2023-03-29 12:00:00,cluster2,server1,cpu2,154
2023-03-29 12:00:00,cluster2,server2,cpu1,122
2023-03-29 12:00:00,cluster2,server2,cpu2,112
2023-03-29 12:15:00,cluster1,server1,cpu1,134
2023-03-29 12:15:00,cluster1,server1,cpu2,145
2023-03-29 12:15:00,cluster1,server2,cpu1,121
2023-03-29 12:15:00,cluster1,server2,cpu2,107
2023-03-29 12:15:00,cluster2,server1,cpu1,167
2023-03-29 12:15:00,cluster2,server1,cpu2,103
2023-03-29 12:15:00,cluster2,server2,cpu1,122
2023-03-29 12:15:00,cluster2,server2,cpu2,177
```

So the data is collected every 15 minutes but the problem is that, due to reboots, outages etc., a cluster might be down for a while meaning there will be missing data for that 15 minute window.

My question is, how can I add that missing time window to my dataframe? The best I've come up with is this monstrosity:

```
df.groupby(["server_cluster", "server", "cpu"]).resample("15min").last().ffill().reset_index("date").reset_index(drop=True).set_index("date")
```

Is there a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
df1 = df.groupby(["server_cluster", "server", "cpu"])
         .resample("15min").last().ffill().droplevel([0,1,2])
```